# MS SQL Server: Assign value to variable and reuse the var within the query

Tags: sql-server, variables, select

I am doing the follwoing e.g.:

```
SELECT name1, name2, left(name1,2) + '_' + left(name2,2), ID, ID + left(name1,2) + '_' + left(name2,2)

from person
```

So `left(name1,2) + '_' + left(name2,2)` is used more than one times. Is there any way I can do this better. I have queries where I have to call the same function chain 10 - 15 times.

Other example:

I some queries I need to get values with a sub-query

e.g.

```
Select name, (Select something from some_table where X=Y) , age from person
```

In some cases I do need the value returned from the sub-query for a different column also.

e.g.

```
Select name, (Select something from some_table where X=Y) , age,
left( (Select something from some_table where X=Y),2) as Test

from person
```

There must be an easier way...right?

Comment: Well it's a bit messy yes. But SQL Server won't execute the subselect two times. Normally he will decide that both subselects return the same and reuse the result for both operations.

Comment: You could wrap your SELECT in a CTE and give speaking aliases. These yo may use in the latter

Comment: In your first example it seems like your table structures are the real issue. But if you find yourself needing to use concatenated portions of columns you might look at computed columns. It makes that kind of thing a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer apply to re-use code, with something like this:

```
Select p.name, x.something, p.age, left(x.something,2) as Test
from person p
outer apply (
    Select something from some_table s where s.X=p.Y
) x
```